# The django-mailer send emails passing query

Tags: python, django, email, queue, django-mailer

I want use queue for send my emails.
For this I use the django-mailer with follow config

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'mailer.backend.DbBackend'
MAILER_EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend' #for test
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'app-messages')
MAILER_EMAIL_MAX_BATCH = 1
MAILER_EMAIL_MAX_DEFERRED = 1
MAILER_EMAIL_THROTTLE = 1000
```

But when I try to send 5 emails It hasn't fall in queue and sending at once.
The my synthetic example

```
def send_email() :
    send_mail(
        'subject',
        'text_template',
        settings.SEND_EMAIL_FROM,
        ['email@host.com'],
        priority=PRIORITY_DEFERRED
    )

send_email(instance.id)
send_email(instance.id)
send_email(instance.id)
send_email(instance.id)
send_email(instance.id)
```

What am I doing wrong? Why the queue is empty and all emails was sent together?

Comment: What is mail.backend.DbBackend?

Comment: @e4c5 that's backend for django-mailer https://github.com/pinax/django-mailer